# How to Test ServiceInterceptor using grpcio-testing in Python

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

I have a proto file like

```
syntax = "proto3";

package hello;

message HelloRequest {
}

message HelloResponse {
}

service HelloService {
    rpc UnaryUnaryHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse) {}
    rpc UnaryStreamHello (HelloRequest) returns (stream HelloResponse) {}
    rpc StreamUnaryHello (stream HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse) {}
    rpc StreamStreamHello (stream HelloRequest) returns (stream HelloResponse) {}
}
```

And then I've generated the base servicer and stubs for it.

I also created a server interceptor for it, `MyServerInterceptor`.

Now I am trying to test the interceptor using [grpcio-testing](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_testing.html), but can't figure it out. I am actually having trouble finding any documentation on how to use the library, which looks like [a known issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/17453).

From that issue, I found [this example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/27481), however I can't figure out how to add interceptors to the test server.

Also, the way the tests use the lower level DESCRIPTORS seems rather clunky. Is there a way to use the generated stubs to make the requests?

Finally, the example shows passing a dict `{}` as `invocation_metadata`, but I thought `invocation_metadata` was supposed to be a list of tuples `List[Tuple[str,str]]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/27481) you posted is not merged yet. I would recommend to test the gRPC service in Python with actual gRPC client/server instead of the mocking library. In this way, you are testing the server logic in the way that a client would.

And you are right about the metadata type, it should be `List[Tuple[str, str]`.